# Align table td tags horizontally after resizing

Tags: html, css

I have a table and when I resize the table for mobile view the td cells appear under each other, but I want them to appear next to each other? How could i achieve this?

Here are some pictures for demonstration.

Here is the table in desktop view:

[image: Here is the table in desktop view]

Here is the table in mobile view:

[image: Here is the table in mobile view]

In this my desired result is to align the "a" cell left and the "d" cell right, "e" next to "g", "h" next to "i" and next to "j", so on....

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-color: rgb(64, 64, 64); border-style: solid; width: 500px; border-width:1px !important;">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color:#404040">
            <td  colspan ="3" style="text-align:center;"><span style="color:#FFFFFF;">Desc</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a
                <div class="tool-tip">
                    <i class="tool-tip__icon">?</i>
                    <p class="tool-tip__info">
                        <span class="info"><span class="info__title">b</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="2">d</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>e
                <div class="tool-tip">
                    <i class="tool-tip__icon">?</i>
                    <p class="tool-tip__info">
                        <span class="info"><span class="info__title">f</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="2">g</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>h</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">i</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">j</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>k</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">l</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">j</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>as
                <div class="tool-tip">
                    <i class="tool-tip__icon">?</i>
                    <p class="tool-tip__info">
                        <span class="info"><span class="info__title">ag</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">asad</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">fjf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>hjkgk</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">qqwe</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">gsdg
                <div class="tool-tip">
                    <i class="tool-tip__icon">?</i>
                    <p class="tool-tip__info">
                        <span class="info"><span class="info__title">szg</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>jk</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">dffg</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">asf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>sdge</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">VS</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">VggS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bgjgjfj</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">13G</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">G56</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

(EDIT)The CSS:

```
<style>
.tool-tip {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}
.tool-tip .tool-tip__icon {
  background: #404040;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: times new roman;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  color:white;
}
.tool-tip .tool-tip__info {
  display: none;
  background: #404040;
  border: 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  padding: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: -20px;
  width: 250px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.tool-tip .tool-tip__info:before, .tool-tip .tool-tip__info:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 7px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  border-color: transparent ;
}
.tool-tip .tool-tip__info:after {
  left: -8px;
  border-right-color:#404040;
}
.tool-tip .tool-tip__info .info {
  display: block;
}
.tool-tip .tool-tip__info .info__title {
  color: white;
}
.tool-tip:hover .tool-tip__info, .tool-tip:focus .tool-tip__info {
  display: inline-block;
}

a:focus + .tool-tip .tool-tip__info {
  display: inline-block;
}

 table, tr, td  {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse

}

 table, th, td  {
    font-size:0.96em;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Hey, can you please share the CSS you are using?

Comment: @Radu033 I edited the post and added the css

Comment: I've downloaded your code, and in my google chrome everything works as it should be: https://prnt.sc/pzrn7n . can you send me the complete file you are working on, there should be some css classes overwriting your classes

Comment: @Radu033 I found another solution, so I've fixed the problem. Maybe the probles was that I had to embed the table into a website and the site's properties overrid mine and changed the table's alignment